# pdf files within iframes are downloading automatically in ie8

Tags: pdf, iframe, internet-explorer-8

I want to display several pdf files within iframes and have written such php code:

```
for ($i=0;$i<count($posts);$i++)
{
   echo '<div class="doc-prev"><iframe src="'.$posts[$i].'" width="640" height="400">   </iframe></div>';
}
```

Everything's fine in Chrome,FF and even IE9, but after opening the page in IE8 an information toolbar appears with question if I really want to download those files. Does anyone know how it could be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try adding the header `Content-Disposition` with value `inline;` ?